# Как пропустить строку в файле CSV при чтении через BuffeReader?Java

Tags: java, файлы, потоки-данных, buffer

Допустим есть файл  `test.csv`, там таблица:

```
 Name   Age  Count
 Bob    25     4
 Sam    45     5
```

Вопрос, какой код написать, чтобы при чтении потока пропускалась первая строка `Name;Age;Count` и начиналась сразу со второй строки где `Bob;25;4`?

Вот code:

```
public class CSVtestclass {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {


        String FileName = "c:\\TestJava\\test.csv";

        File file = new File(FileName);
        Map<String, WordInfo> wordInfoMap = new HashMap<>();


        try(BufferedReader read = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file))){
            String s;
            String wordName;
            HashMap<String, int[]> stringIntegerHashMap = new HashMap<>();
            while( (s = read.readLine()) != null) {
                String[] next = s.split(";");
                wordName = next[0];
                if (stringIntegerHashMap.containsKey(wordName)) {
                    int[] ints = stringIntegerHashMap.get(wordName);
                    ints[0]++;
                    ints[1] += Integer.parseInt(next[3]);
                } else {
                    stringIntegerHashMap.put(wordName, new int[]{1, Integer.parseInt(next[3])});
                }
            }

            for (Map.Entry<String, int[]> pair: stringIntegerHashMap.entrySet()) {
                int[] value = pair.getValue();
                System.out.printf("%s zayavki: %d interakcii: %d%n", pair.getKey(), value[0], value[1]);
            }


        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если это нужно всегда, просто вставьте 1 `readLine` перед циклом чтения.

Если нужно не всегда и разное количество строк то напишите отдельный метод для пропуска строк.

```
void skipLine(BufferedReader reader, int skipLine){
    for(int i =0; i<skipLine; i++)
       reader.readLine();
}
```

Если знаете точно количество символов, которые надо пропустить, то можете использовать `Reader.skip(long n)`

Если нужные вам строки между собой похожи, то можете попробовать отсекать ненужные регулярками.

Comment: можно  на куске моего кода показать куда именно?

Comment: если я все верно понял, то между объявлением HashMap и циклом while. Вообще в любом месте после объявления ридера и до момента чтения. А лучше даже если 1 строку надо пропустить - написать отдельный метод, чтобы через полгода не гадать, что это за readLine тут ненужный =)

Comment: Спасибо дружище!